# Java Servlet (Jetty) streaming performance issue

Tags: android, performance, servlets, jetty, streaming

I'm implementing some application for Android whose main feature is to stream content on phone to any client. Obviously app need some local http server to serve requests from clients. After some research I've stopped with Jetty cause it looks like a suitable solution for Android. So, I implemented streaming servlet like this:

```
// detect file path, basing on MediaStore id    

File file = new File(path);

long fileLength = file.length();

response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK); 
response.setContentType(mime);
response.setContentLength((int) fileLength); 
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
response.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[512*1024];

int readCount;

while((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1){
    os.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}

is.close();
os.close();
```

All worked just fine until I tried to play huge flac file with Hi-End bitrate level (about 170Mb for 8.5 minute file) - now I'm getting constant interruptions on renderer, like an insufficient buffer. I tried to increase buffer size (2x, 4x, 10x and more and more), but seems it has very small result (if ever). I also played with size of buffer for BufferedInputStream, this had same effect.
My renderer is connected via WiFi and pretty close to me. I also tried to play this song with one of apps from Google Play and seems it plays well.

So, my main question - whether it some critical flaw in my implementation? Is there any way to increase performance?